# Ubuntu 20.04 running thinkorswim from applications list

Tags: 20.04, shortcuts

I was able to install thinkorswim as normal. The installer offered to create a desktop icon, I selected this option but no desktop icon was created. I ran thinkorswim from the installer no problem, but the icon on my left menu bar shows the title java-lang-Thread and won't let me add it to favourites. Thinkorswim also does not show up in my applications list and can't be searched for using the super key.

The only way I am able to run thinkorswim is by navigating to the installed folder in the terminal and running:

./thinkorswim

I've tried several guides on creating a .desktop file and I've managed to get it into my applications list but it will not actually run. Here are the .desktop files I tried:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ThinkorSwim
Exec=xdg-open /home/dunnetahl/thinkorswim/thinkorswim
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/dunnetahl/thinkorswim/thinkorswim.ico
Type=Application
Comment=ToS Workstation
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=/home/dunnetahl/thinkorswim/thinkorswim
Name=ThinkorSwim
Comment=ToS Workstation
Icon=/home/dunnetahl/thinkorswim/thinkorswim.ico 
NoDisplay=false
Categories=GTK;AudioVideo
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without 'xdg-open'

Like this:

```
Name=ThinkorSwim
Exec=/home/dunnetahl/thinkorswim/thinkorswim
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/dunnetahl/thinkorswim/thinkorswim.ico
Type=Application
Comment=ToS Workstation
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately no luck

Answer (score 0):

I got help from one of the Thinkorswim technicians today, and what we ended up doing was running the installation file in a brand new folder.  I ended up with a desktop icon.  Something gets corrupted in many of these installation attempts and just has to be tried over, although we did change some folder preferences in the process.